# Does SAP NetWeaver AS Java support all the languages on the JVM or only Java?

Tags: jvm, abap, netweaver

Does SAP NW AS Java support all the language on JVM(Kotlin, Scala, Jython..), or only Java? If not is there a way to use other languages for SAP other than ABAP and Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It depends on the SAP JVM version you have.

I believe that web based languages are available to use in specific contexts, but I believe they require ABAP or JAVA wrapper code.

Check this link out for more information.

https://blogs.sap.com/2011/12/07/sapjvm-overview/

```
Platform            Runtime JDK
As Java 6.40        SAP JVM 4 (via switch)
As Java 7.00        SAP JVM 4 (via switch)
As Java 7.0 EHP3    SAP JVM 4
As Java 7.10        SAP JVM 5
As Java 7.20        SAP JVM 6
As Java 7.30        SAP JVM 6
```